# Vercel build error, Unable to find lambda for route

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am trying to build and deploy a NextJS application using the Vercel CLI.

The strategy is to pre-build and then deploy the pre-built artifacts.

```
vercel build
vercel deploy --prebuilt
```

I am getting the following errors:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do exactly what you wanted to do and I got this error.
If you use Windows cmd to run the command, you need to install WSL and run the command after installing prerequisites like node.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. This actually helped me with the error. Details below in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the Vercel CLI itself.

https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/8564

https://github.com/vercel/vercel/pull/8530

Answer (score 0):

I actually followed @Ali Roshani's idea, and installed WSL on my Windows 11 workstation and it worked!

[How to install WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)

Then I got Ubuntu running on WSL and then I had to install **node**.

[How to install node on WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl)

Everything worked after that.